# Кнопка-слайдер

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!

Необходимо сделать кнопку, на подобие как у iPad.
Вот, что сделал я:

Html

```
 <div id="slider">
    <div id="runner"></div>
    <span class="left">Работает</span>
    <span class="right">Не работает</span>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#slider {
   width: 160px;
   height: 30px;
   font: bold 12px/30px Arial;
   background: #636363;
   border-radius: 5px;
   color: #fff;
   position: relative;  
}

#slider .left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#slider .right {
   float: right;
   margin-right: 5px;
}

#runner {
   width: 80px;
   height: 28px;
   background: #d5d5d5;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-radius: 5px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

jQuery

```
init();

function init(){ 
  $("#runner").draggable({ containment:'parent' }); 
}

$('#slider .right').click(function() {
  $('#runner').animate({'right' : '0'}, 300);
});

$('#slider .left').click(function() {
  $('#runner').animate({'left' : '0'}, 300);
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как заставить данный код функционировать по принципу переключателя - (работает / не работает). Кроме этого, необходимо чтобы переключатель срабатывал и при перетаскивании, и по событию click();. В данном примере по событию click(), переключатель срабатывает, но только два раза, а все последующие разы,клик по левой стороне работает, а по правой нет.

С уважением, Александр

Comment: *Для коментов ниже - уже нет места.*

Продолжение: В конце концов, покажите на jsFiddle свой реальный код. И желательно с элементами, которые могут влиять на слайдер.

Comment: Deonis, Вот то, что у меня в js http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/m4vnQ/

Comment: Deonis, в общем, вся проблема в Twitter Bootstrap. Отключил вот этот фаил: bootstrap.min.css и все заработало. Без Bootstrap'a ни как...

Comment: @Александр Колпаков, ну, вот )) Не сам файл влияет на работу, а скорее всего, что какой-то определенный стиль. В общем, [делаем поправки](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/cfJGs/10/)

Comment: Я даже и не знаю, как Вас отблагодарить... Спасибо, что вытерпели меня. Deonis, может быть подскажите, какой литературой обложиться, чтобы так же ориентироваться в JS как Вы. Спасибо.

Comment: Не приувеличивайте моих достоинств )) Хороший поисковик, терпение и логика - это всё, что вам на данном этапе надо. Если английский знаете хорошо, то читайте [мануалы из первоисточника](http://docs.jquery.com/) и [готовые решения библиотеки](http://jqueryui.com/). Если с ингишем не в ладах или просто лень, то есть [хороший сайт](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5) (*он не единственный*) по этим же темам на русском.

Comment: Deonis, приветствую. Всплыл еще один баг. В тех документах, где используется выше разобранный скрипт, Datepicker работает, а где нет блока div id="slider", не работает. Проблему решил, вставив в данный элемент - display: none;, но хотелось бы более правильный вариант.

Comment: @Александр Колпаков, что-то я не понял. Вы хотите сказать, что присутствие вашей кнопки-переключателя влияет на правильную работу datepicker-а? )) Или вы опечаталиь и имели ввиду противополжное? Если все-таки второй вариант, то проверьте, чтоб у ваших элементов не было одинакового id-шника. Это первое, что приходит в голову. А если нет, то чуть подробней опишите проблему.

P.S. Возможности добавлять коментарии, в этом вопросе, уже нет, так что создайте по этой теме новый вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/cfJGs/). Только заметил, что вы подредактировали вопрос, но если сами не справитесь, то постараюсь помочь.

**UPD**

[Вот вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/cfJGs/10/), который, я надеюсь, то, что вам нужен

Comment: Deonis, будьте добры, помогите пожалуйста.
На сколько я понимаю, чтобы переключатель был рабочим, он должен выдавать что-то вроде true или false, в зависимости от положения #runner. или я не прав? И еще момент - не могу понять почему по клику не срабатывает?

Comment: @Александр Колпаков, ответ в апдейте

Comment: Deonis, ни чего не понимаю, в jsFiddle все работает, прописываю у себя в редакторе, - глючит, не реагирует на click()по левой стороне. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: @Александр Колпаков, вы последний комментарий мой читали? Ссылка в ответе обновлена уже на исправленный ответ

Comment: Да, читал. Повторюсь, в jsFiddle все работает, но когда я копирую код из jsFiddle, то он работать перестает, а именно не срабатывает click по левой стороне. (Имею ввиду, что не работает у меня на машине)

Comment: Сложно угадать, что может повлиять. Сделайте таким образом - добавьте в код это:

    slider.click(function(e){
        _move(e.pageX - offsetW);
        alert(e.pageX - offsetW + ' <> ' + offsetW);
    });

При клике на левую сторону, значение **e.pageX - offsetW** должно быть меньше, чем **offsetW**. Попробуйте разобраться, почему это может быть не так.

Comment: Значение e.pageX - offsetW у меня больше чем offsetW. Как это исправить?

Comment: @Александр Колпаков, ну с математикой же вы знакомы? )) Подкорректируйте, посчитайте ширину слайдера, ширину бегунка, высчитайте диапозон значений для клика слева и справа... В общем-то, для одноразовой задачи, достаточно указать статические значения (тем более, если знаете реальные размеры), вместо того, чтоб их вычислять динамически.